# Drupal resize image on the fly

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to resize images on the fly and cache the result with Drupal?

I have some big images (e.g. 2000x2000px) and I want to display a preview of the e.g. 100x100px.

I know there is a [theme_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) function. But it seams to only create the `<img>` with the right size and not effectively resize the image.

I look at modules/images/image.admin.inc and they used the function `[image_style_create_derivative][2]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use Drupal's Image styles (Configuration -> Media -> Image styles). There you should create your style.

Then, on front-end, when ever you want to display image with that style (in that resolution) you can use image_style_url() function:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

It accepts 2 parameters - one is image style machine name and other is image URI, which you can get if you print out all image field properties.

You can also select image styles from back-end interface...i.e. when creating a view for some image you can select to be displayed in specific image style.

In both cases those image styles are generated the first time image is used.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. Do you know a solution without using the Drupal Backend? Only by using PHP.

Comment: You can do it on your own too, by using PHP image manipulation libraries, like GD library or Image magic.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment on MilanG's answer, using image_style_url() is the best option on the backend.  There is also

https://www.drupal.org/project/resp_img

which may be something worth looking into.  From a UX perspective, you don't want to force the user to load a 2000x2000 px image every time they load the page. Regardless of the outputted size, the image is still going to render as a 2000x2000 px image with a large size.  image_style_url() or using image styles in the GUI create a new file that will load much quicker and is the preferred method.